# Effect something have or get"

Tags: sentence-construction, academic-writing

Do they have the same meaning:

> 1. The effect "y" has when the value of "x" changes is called rate of change.
> 2. The effect "y" gets when the value of "x" changes is called rate of change.

Is there usually a difference when we use has or gets with effect?

Comment: (2) is not idiomatic. Something has an effect, it doesn't get it.

Comment: (2) sounds unidiomatic as Kate said, and (1) is not an elegant scientific writing either in my humble opinion. Both sentence sound off to my learner ears.

Comment: On second thoughts - Do you mean that "y" has an effect on something, or that something else has an effect on it? In the latter case, you need to say _The effect on "y"_

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the usual convention for x and y then

> The effect on y when x changes is called the rate of change

as @KateBunting suggested in comments. Neither of your suggestions sounds good although the first is better. I think it is off-topic on this site to discuss whether that really is a good definition of rate of change as that is really for a mathematics site.